Modeling heterogenity of sucess probabilities of bernoulli sequences using probability distribution
I would like to model a collection of n binary sequences using Bernoulli distribution like
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
1&0&1&0&1&0 \\
1&1&1&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$
As is show, each have different frequency of 1. Is there a family of distribution that I can use to sample 4 points that are very different from each other ?
I would like to be able to control how varied they are from each other.

"I would like to able to create a distribution that outputs a vector of length 4" - Distributions don't 'output' numbers. I'm not sure what is being asked here, since you already state that the sequences are given by Bernoulli trials.

@Firebug Sorry, I meant sample a vector of dimension of 4. For instance the sample can be [0.4,0.4,0.4,0.9]. Or it could be [0.1,0.9,0.2,0.6]. I initially thought of a Dirichlet distribution but the values sum up to 1 in that case. The reason I would like to do this is to control the heterogeneity of the components ([0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4] vs [0.1,0.9,0.6,0.25]. I understand that my explanation i

Is there any assumption on the interdependence between sequences?

@Firebug Atm I make them independent of each other. As I type this, maybe my question is ill-posed but eod I want to be able to create n matrices like the one described above with the same frequencies for the four rows and create another bag of n matrices with varying frequencies. I would like to denote a number that measures the heterogeneity of the frequency

@Firebug Thanks to you I was able to refine my question bettter.

I realised that what I want is a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}_{[a,b]}$. Choosing a,b in [0,1], I can control how varied I want the samples to be. If I reduce b-a, I have close to very similar samples, the extreme case of this would be the dirac delta function.
